# Current Location input in LatLng causing crash

Tags: android, google-api

I'm trying to put a marker at my current location (using the google maps api). While direct input values in the LatLng are working, indirectly calling currentLocation.getLatitude() and currentLocation.getLongitude() is crashing my application for some reason, i know it's this line because the app doesn't crash until i add this line.

Here's my MapsActivity class-

```
    package com.example.shreyass.tourist;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements       OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Location currentLocation;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super`enter code here`.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    googleApiClient.connect();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
 }


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker at current location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1);
    }
    else {
        currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

Comment: try putting in a try catch adn find what exception you are getting

Comment: Could you please post your Logcat too..

Comment: Shijil's answer worked guys. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this changes..

```
  public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Location currentLocation;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super`enter code here`.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);



        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used. 
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available. 
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used. 
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, 
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia. 
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install 
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has 
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app. 
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;

        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        googleApiClient.connect();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1);
        }
        else {
            currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera 
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker at current location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! This worked! I marked the answer, but I'll be glad if you could still explain to me why was my code crashing?

Comment: Oh wait, I'm guessing because the map gets ready before the googleApiClient could connect?